# Why does Tensor Flow add a dimension to my input & output?

Tags: tensorflow

Here is my code:

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

TFDataType = tf.float16

XTrain = tf.cast(tf.ones((10,10)), dtype=TFDataType)
YTrain = tf.cast(tf.ones((10,10)), dtype=TFDataType)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(1, dtype=TFDataType, input_shape=(10, 10)))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, dtype=TFDataType, input_shape=(10, 10)))

print(model.summary())
```

I am feeding it a 2 dimensional matrix.  But when I see the model summary, I see:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
2021-08-23 13:32:18.716788: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:176] hostname: DESKTOP-TLG9US3
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense (Dense)                (None, 10, 1)             11        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 10, 2)             4         
=================================================================
Total params: 15
Trainable params: 15
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Why is the model asking for a 3 Dimensional (None, 10, 1) array?

How do I pass an array that meets the dimensionality of (None, 10, 1)?

I cannot call numpy.ones(None, 10, 1).  I cannot reshape the array with -1 in the first dimension.

Answer (score 0):

In your first layer the code input_shape=(10, 10) adds the extra dimension to account for the batch size of the data. Note you only need this code for the FIRST layer  in your model so remove input_shape=(10, 10) in your second layer.